# Calling python file in Variables section of robotframework 3.2

Tags: python, cloud, robotframework

replace `"Variables config"` with `"Variables  /path/CLOUD234/__init__.py"` in robot framework .Cloud instance is defined at run time .In each run the value changes ,so I have created a python file initpath.py as follows with fun() keyword .It will return the required path .How can I call it in Variables section of robot framework ? Thank you in advance.

```
import socket
import re
import os

def fun():

    name = socket.gethostname()
    pattern = ".*CLOUD[0-9]*"
    hname = re.findall(pattern,name)
    cloud_instance = hname[0].replace("-","_")
    init_file = "/path/{}/__init__.py".format(cloud_instance)
    return init_file
```

Comment: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files

Answer (score 2):

Variables section do not execute any code.
I suggest you run the python under testcase/suite up and use `Set Test Variable` to set the variable.

Comment: While variables section does not allow this but  `*** Settings ***`  section does with `Variables`  does. See https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files

Answer (score 0):

Try following: Here, you are not required to use any variables/section to call py file.

Under `*** Settings ***` section add

```
Library initpath.py
```